# Inherited generic as a function parameter

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, parameter-passing

How can I accomplish this?

```
class A { }
class B : A { }

class X<T> where T : A { }
class Y<T> : X<T> where T : A { }

private static void f(X<A> x) { }

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Y<B> y = new Y<B>();
    f(y); // Compiler error here
}
```

Y inherited from X, B from A, but it doesn't get compiled.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the function definition to:

```
private static void f<T>(X<T> x) where T : A { }
```

As you have defined it, you are saying that `f()` must be passed an instance of `X<A>`. By defining as I've shown here, you are saying that `f()` takes any class that has `X<A>` as a parent.